# Creating soap request with array of complex types

Tags: c#, soap

I'm consuming a web service and I have this From the wsdl:

```
<xs:complexType name="Person">
    <xs:sequence>          
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="PersonAddresses" type="ns:PersonAddress" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

from the xsd:

```
<!--Complex Type for PersonAddress-->
<xs:complexType name="PersonAddress">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Address" type="Address" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<!--Complex Type for Address-->
<xs:complexType name="Address">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Addr1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="Addr2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="City" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="State" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="Zip" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Using the generated proxy, I create an Collection of PersonAddress and add Address objects to it.

```
...
var convertedAddresses = new PersonAddress[addressesToCounvert.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < addresses.Count; i++)
{
    convertedAddresses[i] = ConvertAddress(addresses[i]);
}
person.PersonAddresses = convertedAddresses;
...
```

When I submit the request, it looks like this

```
<PersonAddress>
    <Address>
        ...
    </Address>
</PersonAddress>
<PersonAddress>
    <Address>
        ...
    </Address>
</PersonAddress>
```

So what am I doing wrong..the needed format would be

```
<PersonAddress>
    <Address>
        ...
    </Address>
    <Address>
        ...
    </Address>
</PersonAddress>
```

Thanks for any input

Comment: Can you change `maxOccurs="1"` to `maxOccurs="unbounded"` for `PersonAddress/Address` in the schema?

Comment: thanks! This appears to be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the output you're getting matches the WSDL/XSD definitions. Based on the WSDL, a `<Person>` element can contain multiple `<PersonAddress>` elements. Based on the XSD, a `<PersonAddress>` element can contain 0 or 1 `<Address>` elements. Valid contstructions using the information provided would be:

```
<Person>
 <PersonAddress>
  <Address>
    ...
  </Address>
 </PersonAddress>
</Person>
<Person>
 <PersonAddress>
  <Address>
      ...
  </Address>
 </PersonAddress>
 <PersonAddress>
  <Address>
      ...
  </Address>
 <PersonAddress>
</Person>
```

Please also note that there is an inconsistency in the spelling of `<PersonAddress>`. In the WSDL code you provided a `<Person>` element is defined to contain 0 to many `<PersonAddresses>` elements (note the pluralization of "Addresses"). I assumed, for the purposes of this answer, that this was just a typo and that `<PersonAddresses>` should really have been spelled as `<PersonAddress>` in the WSDL. I wanted to make sure to point this out in case the problem is simply that you're using the wrong object (i.e. maybe there is a `<PersonAddresses>` complex type that allows 1 to many `<Address>` elements within it)

Comment: thanks! Changing to allow 1 to many appears to be the issue.  I need to get the provider of the service to change it if they want the request format to change.

Comment: I don't think I agree with that approach. Why does the provider of the service need to change something? What data requirement isn't satisfied with the current WSDL/XSD?